# How can I print a 2d array in different ways

Tags: python

I have got an array like this one `a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]]`. I want to be able to split it up so that it prints it out like the first item from the lists on one line and then the second items from both lists on the next line. 1 5 (newline) 2 6 (newline) 3 7 (newline) 4 8

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Do you have an output example?

Comment: `print(*["{} {}".format(*i) for i in zip(*a)], sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Use simple loop and zip:

```
>>> for i,j in zip(*a): print(i, j)
... 
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Comment: File "/Users/owennichol/PycharmProjects/untitled2/AA.py", line 2, in <module>
    for i,j in zip(*a): print(i, j)
ValueError: too many values to unpack How do I fix this. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @OwenNichol If this is happening, list `a` must be different there in that file `AA.py`.

Answer (score 0):

use `zip()` function and `*` (unpack operator)

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

for item in zip(*a):
    print (*item)
```

or with list comprehension:

```
[print(*item) for item in zip(*a)]
```

output:

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

if yout sublist are different length you can use for Python 3 `itertools.zip_longest()` or `itertools.izip_longest` (Python 2.6+):

> **itertools.zip_longest()**
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted.
>
> syntax:
>
> `itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)`

example:

```
import itertools
a = [[1, 2, 3],[5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13]]

for item in itertools.zip_longest(*a):
    print (*item)
```

output:

```
1 5 10
2 6 11
3 7 12
None 8 13
None 9 None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]]

output = '\n'.join([' '.join([str(values[i])  for values in a]) for i in range(len(a[0]))])

print (output)
```

Output:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers have been posted. I am posting an answer that will avoid for loops.
This would do, as well, if numpy is allowed.

```py
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]]
a = np.array(a)
print(a.T)
```

prints the following

```py
[[1 5]
 [2 6]
 [3 7]
 [4 8]]
```